# How do I replace the spectrwm bar with tint2, while maintaining dmenu?

Tags: dmenu, tint2

I am running the spectrwm window manager on a WattOS Microwatt R10 (Ubuntu 16.04 based) install. I would like to do the following:

1. Replace the spectrwm bar with tint2.
2. Need tint2 to appear on all of the workspaces, not just one as now.
3. Need to be able to use dmenu with the dmenu_run command.